# C Constant structures containing arrays of different lengths on the stack

Tags: c, struct, stack

I'm interested in creating a structure in C that (among other POD types) contains an array, and then creating global instances of this on the stack. The array length is known at compile time, but will be different for each instance of the struct. The values inside each instance of the struct will not change, and so should therefore be set to const.

Currently I have the following code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

#include "stdio.h"


typedef struct A
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int* z;
} A_t;

const A_t test[2]  = { {1,1, (int[3]){1,1,1}     },
                       {2,2, (int[5]){2,2,2,2,2} }
                     };

int main( void )
{
    printf( "test[0]: %d %d (%d, %d, %d)\n",
        test[0].x,
        test[0].y,
        test[0].z[0],
        test[0].z[1],
        test[0].z[2] );
    printf( "test[1]: %d %d (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)\n",
        test[1].x,
        test[1].y,
        test[1].z[0],
        test[1].z[1],
        test[1].z[2],
        test[1].z[3],
        test[1].z[4] );
    printf( "\n\n" );


    return;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

This will be working on an embedded system where the heap is extremely limited, so I want to avoid malloc unless I absolutely have to. I also want to stick to C89 if possible, since VS2008 does not support C99 (I think).

This works fine in GCC (4.8.1 via MinGW), but doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2008. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get it to work on both compilers?

For reference, here is the error message from VS2008:

> c:\temp\test_variable_length_arrays\bob.c(15) : error C2059: syntax
>   error : '{'
>
> c:\temp\test_variable_length_arrays\bob.c(15) : error C2059: syntax
>   error : '}'
>
> c:\temp\test_variable_length_arrays\bob.c(17) : error C2059: syntax
>   error : '}

Thanks in advance for all comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you want to use C89 because VS2008 *doesn't* support it? Incidentally, variable length arrays are only available in C99 - C89/C90 don't support them (and neither does C++).

Comment: this is not vla. and c89 does not support vla.

Comment: I agree that VLA is not a good description for what I want to do; however, I'm not sure what the correct terminology is. I don't want to vary the array length at run-time, but I do need to be able to have different length arrays at compile-time, described by the same structure definition.

Comment: GoBusto, thanks for spotting the typo, I have corrected it. I mean that VS2008 has very little (if any) C99 support.

Comment: you can declare your structure has flexible array member. like this: `struct s { int n; double d[]; };`. how to use it: `int m = /* some value */;
struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));`. please reference to c11 standard 6.7.2.1 for detail.

Comment: Thanks, but that uses malloc, which I want to avoid.

Comment: i see. your software runs on embedded system. maybe you can try to ask the problem you want to solve directly, since what you can do with c is limited. by asking the problem directly, people may have better proposal. asking other questions to hide your original problem could be time wasting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: No VLAs here. I removed the tag. And be so kind and adjust your wording.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the thread title to avoid mentioning VLA, I agree that was confusing. I'm not sure how best to describe it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could allocate the inner structs globally, then assign into the struct at run time, e.g.

```
int x[] = {1,1,1};
int y[] = {3,3,3,3,3};

int main()
{
    A_t str = {2, 2, y};
}
```

I believe some compilers will also let you move the definition of `str` to global scope to make it fully static.

Comment: Since the initializer `y` is a constant expression, you can move str to global scope.

Comment: Thanks, this is one possibility (it works in both GCC and VS2008); however, we're looking at having the "test" array (in my code example above) to be over 100 elements long, and this could get messy. Also, the int* may need to be changed to a variable-length array of another type of structure (depending on customer requirements), so this could balloon quite quickly :)

Comment: @BriantheDog: you may want to write a script or other C program that generates the initialization code; at least that way you won't have to hand-hack it every time something changes.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go - use a script to write the struct definition and initialization code. The Compound Literals were added in C99 and so are not present in VS2008 - they are added in VS2013 ([see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx)). I'll mark this as the solution (and ask our team to upgrade to VS2013!). Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is choking on the following:

```
const A_t test[2]  = { {1,1, (int[3]){1,1,1}     },
                       {2,2, (int[5]){2,2,2,2,2} }
```

specifically, the *compound literals* `(int[3]){1,1,1}` and `(int[5]){2,2,2,2,2}`; compound literals were introduced with C99, and will not be recognized by a C89 compiler such as Visual Studio.

Does this *have* to be compiled by Visual Studio?  Can you build it with MinGW (Windows-native GNU compiler) or with gcc under cygwin, perhaps?  If not, slugonamission's solution is probably going to be the path of least resistance.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it has to compile with both gcc in Linux (for the chip firmware) and VS2008 in Windows (for the customer interface software) - otherwise the overnight Jenkins test will fail and I will get an email :) I am trying to avoid doing what slugonamission suggested because I am likely to have >100 elements in my "test" array, and that would then get very fiddly.

Comment: @BriantheDog: That's...unfortunate.  I'll repeat the suggestion in my other comment; you may want to write a script or other program to generate the initialization code, rather than hand-hacking it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

See comments about `(int[3]){1,2,3}` syntax. But there is no guarantee that those arrays will persist in memory (they are temporaries). You could define them as global variables, and set the pointers to them:

```
static int az1[] = {1, 2, 3};
static int az2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
const A_t test[2]  = { {1,1, az1 },
                       {2,2, az2 }
                     };
```

Comment: `int *p = (int []){2, 4};` this expression is valid. see C11 standard p104 example 1. it's a compound literal initialization.

Comment: Unfortunately, compound literals postdate C89/C90, which is the latest standard that Visual Studio 2008 supports.